# GROUP BY intervals of integer values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, intervals

I need to sum up linear objects' length and to group them by intervals of several years. I have one table storing my objects like this :

```
- gid serial NOT NULL, 
- year INTEGER, 
- the_geom geometry(MULTILINESTRING) ;
```

I need a result like this:

```
period          | length
----------------+-----------
 2005 - 2014    | 18.6
 1995 - 2004    | 16.1
 1985 - 1994    | 7.6
 1975 - 1984    | 19.0
 1965 - 1974    | 28.2
 1945 - 1964    | 10.2
 before 1945    | 0.1
```

I can't find out on the Web how to perform this, except by producing each line with a different query and to use `UNION ALL` to merge them together, which is not so good ...

Comment: No information on how you compute "length"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a *discriminant function*, which one can create in a number of ways. For your purposes a case statement is just the ticket, something like:

```
select case
         when t.year >= 2015 then '2015-present'
         when t.year >= 2005 then '2005-2014'
         when t.year >= 1995 then '1995-2004'
         when t.year >= 1985 then '1985-1994'
         when t.year >= 1975 then '1975-1984'
         when t.year >= 1965 then '1965-1974'
         when t.year >= 1955 then '1955-1964'
         when t.year >= 1945 then '1945-1954'
         when t.year <  1945 then 'before 1945'
         else                     'no year given'
       end as period ,
       sum( compute_length_from_geometry( t.geometry) ) as length
from some_table t
where .
      .
      .
group by case
           when t.year >= 2015 then '2015-present'
           when t.year >= 2005 then '2005-2014'
           when t.year >= 1995 then '1995-2004'
           when t.year >= 1985 then '1985-1994'
           when t.year >= 1975 then '1975-1984'
           when t.year >= 1965 then '1965-1974'
           when t.year >= 1955 then '1955-1964'
           when t.year >= 1945 then '1945-1954'
           when t.year <  1945 then 'before 1945'
           else                     'no year given'
         end as period
order by case
           when t.year >= 2015 then  1
           when t.year >= 2005 then  2
           when t.year >= 1995 then  3
           when t.year >= 1985 then  4
           when t.year >= 1975 then  5
           when t.year >= 1965 then  6
           when t.year >= 1955 then  7
           when t.year >= 1945 then  8
           when t.year <  1945 then  9
           else                     10
         end as period
```

You might also just consider a bracketing table, either permanent or temporary, something like:

```
create table report_period
(
  period_id          int         not null ,
  year_from          int         not null ,
  year_thru          int         not null ,
  period_description varchar(32) not null ,

  primary key clustered ( period_id ) ,
  unique nonclustered ( year_from , year_thru ) ,

)
insert report_period values ( 1 , 2015 , 9999 , '2015-present' )
insert report_period values ( 2 , 2005 , 2014 , '2005-2014'    )
insert report_period values ( 3 , 1995 , 2004 , '1995-2004'    )
insert report_period values ( 4 , 1985 , 1994 , '1985-1994'    )
insert report_period values ( 5 , 1975 , 1984 , '1975-1984'    )
insert report_period values ( 6 , 1965 , 1974 , '1965-1974'    )
insert report_period values ( 7 , 1955 , 1964 , '1955-1964'    )
insert report_period values ( 8 , 1945 , 1954 , '1945-1954'    )
insert report_period values ( 9 , 0000 , 1944 , 'pre-1945'     )
```

Then your query simply becomes something like

```
select p.period_description as period ,
       sum( compute_length_from_geometry( t.geometry ) ) as length
from report_period p
join some_table    t on t.year between p.year_from and p.year_thru
group by p.period_id ,
         p.period_description
order by p.period_id
```

you can even use *derived tables* to get the same effect

```
select p.period_description as period ,
       sum( compute_length_from_geometry( t.geometry ) ) as length
from (           select 1 as period_id , 2015 as year_from , 9999 as year_thru , '2015-present' as period_description
       UNION ALL select 2 as period_id , 2005 as year_from , 2014 as year_thru , '2005-2014' as period_description
       UNION ALL select 3 as period_id , 1995 as year_from , 2004 as year_thru , '1995-2004' as period_description
       ...
     ) p
join some_table    t on t.year between p.year_from and p.year_thru
group by p.period_id ,
         p.period_description
order by p.period_id
```

Alternatively, you can also simply do integer division, something like

```
period_id = ( 2014 - t.year ) / 10
```

This will give you a period identifier with the domain

- > 0: 2015 or later
- 0: 2005-2014
- -1: 1995-2004
- -2: 1985-1994
- -3: 1975-1984
- -4: 1965-1974
- -5: 1955-1964
- -6: 1945-1954
- < -7: before 1945

Then just add/subtract an appropriate offset to move the zero-point (or change the computation offset in years).

This, however, will usually negate the use of any indices on the column `year` since it's now an *expression*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the following gets the length:

```
select year, length(the_geo) as len
from table
```

Then your problem is to find consecutive years with the same length.  I like the following trick for finding such sequences, assuming that you have one value for every year:

```
select min(year) || '-' || max(year), len
from  (select year, length(the_geo) as len,
              (row_number() over (order by year) -
               row_number() over (partition by length(the_geo) order by year)
              ) as grp
       from table
      ) t
group by grp, len
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the result of an **integer division**, effectively truncating to multiples of the divisor - 10 in your case. Shift by 5 to achieve your partitions:

```
SELECT min(year)::text || ' - ' || max(year) AS period
     , sum(length(the_geom)) AS "length"
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY (year + 5) / 10
ORDER  BY min(year) DESC;
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html)

> `/`   division (integer division truncates the result)

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the bracketing table report_period is excellent and by far the simpliest to me. Thanks very muck Nicholas (and all) !